# Read vertically all the values of all the possible combinations of an unknown number of lists with different sizes in Python

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

I want implement a function that combines **vertically** all the elements of an **unknown number of lists** in Python. Each list has a **different size**. 
E.g., this is the list of list and each row is a list:

```
A0, A1
B0
C0, C1, C2
```

Then I would like to print

```
A0, B0, C0
A0, B0, C1
A0, B0, C2
A1, B0, C0
A1, B0, C1
A1, B0, C2
```

Note that in the example there are 3 lists but they could also more or less, not necessary 3. 
My problem is that I don't have idea how to solve it. I tough to implement a recursive method, in which if some condition is satisfied then print the value, else call recursively the function. Here the pseudo-code:

```
def printVertically(my_list_of_list, level, index):
    if SOME_CONDITION:
        print str(my_list_of_list[index])

    else:
        for i in range (0, int(len(my_list_of_list[index]))):
            printVertically(my_list_of_list, level-1, index)
```

Here the main code:

```
list_zero = []
list_zero.append("A0")
list_zero.append("B0")
list_zero.append("C0")

list_one = []
list_one.append("A1")

list_two = []
list_two.append("A2")
list_two.append("B2")

list_three = []
list_three.append("A3")
list_three.append("B3")
list_three.append("C3")
list_three.append("D3")


my_list_of_list = []
my_list_of_list.append(list_zero)
my_list_of_list.append(list_one)
my_list_of_list.append(list_two)
my_list_of_list.append(list_three)


level=int(len(my_list_of_list))
index=0
printVertically(my_list_of_list, level, index)
```

*level* is the length of the list of list and *index* should represent the index of a specific list used when I want to print a specific element. Well, no idea how to proceed. Any hint?

I have searched but in all solutions, people knew the number of lists or the number of elements in each list, like these links:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143934/using-zip-to-read-a-file-vertically-and-search-through-the-zipped-list)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707433/reading-files-as-both-vertical-lists-and-horizental-listspython-3-2)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990003/how-can-i-find-all-the-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Please explain how you get from your input to your desired output; maybe a complete example (no ellipses!) would help.

Comment: @ScottHunter I improved it

Comment: Could you show how `index` should be used, and a non-zero example with expected output?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you want here is the cross-product of the various sets.  You can do this with Python's **itertools.product** method.  Documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).  Something like:

```
import itertools
a_list = ["A0", "A1"]
b_list = ["B0"]
c_list = ["C0", "C1", "C2"]
for combo in itertools.product(a_list, b_list, c_list):
    print combo
```

Output:

```
('A0', 'B0', 'C0')
('A0', 'B0', 'C1')
('A0', 'B0', 'C2')
('A1', 'B0', 'C0')
('A1', 'B0', 'C1')
('A1', 'B0', 'C2')
```

Does that get you moving?

---

Example with one overarching list:

```
my_list_list = [a_list, b_list, c_list]
for combo in itertools.product(*my_list_list):
    print combo
```

... and we get the same output

Comment: I am testing this code but I don't know what I should put instead of `...` for printing all the combinations.. Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thanks :)

Comment: one more question. Instead of specifying each list in the method parameter like this `itertools.product(a_list, b_list, c_list)`, how can I specify only the list of lists? I have tried this `itertools.product(my_list_of_list)` but it does not print any combination. Thanks.

Comment: ... there you go ... :-)